# How to change screen resolution? i tried everything

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, resolution

I have ubuntu 14.04.1, radeon r7 260x and processor intel i3 4150. ubuntu is installed on partition. its stuck on resolution 1024x768 but my monitor has a resolution of 1920x1080. i have tried installing proprietary drivers for graphics and tried downloading screen apps but i cant change it. On displey setting monitor is unknown. So how to change it?

Comment: try running this in your terminal :

 `xrandr --output LVDS --mode 1024x768`.  

You can change the resolution to whatever you want

Comment: try upgrading the kernel

Answer (score 0):

The Workaround here should fix this issue: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Unable%20to%20change%20Screen%20resolution%20in%20Ubuntu#Workaround

Comment: Nope, doest work